# Configuring Associated WCF Web Role IP on Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, azure-web-roles

I have an Azure project that contains a WCF Services Web Role and an ASP.NET Forms web role, I use 2 instances of each. The ASP.NET Forms web role will regularly call the WCF Services Web Role through standard service references through tcp binding configured in the Web.config like this.

```
<endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:666/EventService.svc"
    behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehaviour" binding="netTcpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="TCPBinding" contract="EventService.IEventService"
    name="EventService" />
```

The problem I am having is that currently I have no way to deploy these roles without manually editing the web.config files after each deployment (because the IP endpoint addresses which these roles deploy on may change).

The way I have considered resolving this issue is by intercepting the `WebRole.OnStart()` event and using `RoleEnvironment.Roles["MyWCFServices"].Instances`, then modifying the Web.config file directly through `Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager` to reference the correct WCF Service IP.

However before I go this route could someone please confirm there isn't an easier way to accomplish IP referencing between web roles in the Azure platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have different web roles for WCF and ASP.Net, their url would only differ by port number, why do you want to bind to IP address?

For such variation you can user [web.config transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx) and define web.config entries for production deployment, by creating a deployment config such as `web.cloud.config`.

**Update**: If the endpoint is internal then the above model does not apply. IP gets generated randomly and has to binded at runtime. See this [post](http://dunnry.com/blog/2010/05/28/HostingWCFInWindowsAzure.aspx)

Comment: Thank for you answer but unfortunately this is not correct. The WCF Service web role and the ASP.NET forms web roles have distinct IP addresses under the default deployment. (Although perhaps this is a result of something I have done)

Comment: You don't use IP address, but names such as myservice.cloudapp.net:8080/wcfservice.svc

Comment: Well I feel like a complete idiot. I never considered that would work as I only exposed a private endpoint I just assumed it wouldn't be available through the public "domain". Talk about overcomplicating the situation. Thank you so very much...

Comment: So after further testing, this solution doesn't infact work, as previously thought unless the endpoint is public (which in my case isnt an option) using the cloud service domain name fails to resolve to the WCF Services when the endpoint is a private address.

Comment: Well you are right, internal endpoints are not exposed externally and get assigned ip+port at runtime. So you need to do discovery and bind at runtime

Comment: Yeah which is basically the same approach as mine except in this case its dynamic (which obviously allows for some load balancing code - which is nice). I'll mark the question as answered again as this basically confirms my assumptions. Thanks very much for your help, sincerely appreciated.